# Reading temperature from transducer via MODBUS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting garbage back when I read from temp transducer device.
This is modbus. Code is Python.

```
ComPort = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate=9600,bytesize=8,parity='N',stopbits=1, timeout=1,)
 
Temphex = b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\xC4\x0B'
ComPort.write(Temphex)

temp = ComPort.read(8)
print(temp)

ComPort.close()
```

My response is `b'\x01\x03\x04\nJ\x13\x90\xd5'`.

I'm getting some garbage: `nJ`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you're getting *garbage* back? Python represents printable ASCII codes not by their hexa-code but with the character.

Comment: `print(''.join(rf'\x{c:02x}' for c in temp))` -> `\x01\x03\x04\x0a\x4a\x13\x90\xd5`.